# Do I need to `ping` connected websocket connections?

Tags: sockets, tcp, websocket

I would like to keep the Websocket connection alive for an undefined amount of time. The socket will ideally be sending data every so often but this is not assured, and I also would not like to make assumptions since a user can be in an idle state.

I have an object that stores references to all websocket connections. Would it be appropriate for me to schedule a function every x number of minutes? seconds? that basically iterates through all the connections, pings them and then discards those that haven't received pongs? Or do I need to enable a flag that automatically keeps the connection alive?

I am using the [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) library on my server, but create websocket connections natively on the client.

Comment: I'm against this. If some netadmin responsible for some router or other device in the middle of the connection has decided that connections through it are precious enough to be dropped, you really have no business trying to deceive him/it into not doing so. And in any case you can't actually stop it from happening: you still have to deal with dropped connections; so where is the benefit? It is notable that HTTP, which is approximately the most-used application protocol on the planet, doesn't do this.

Comment: Well then how would you rule out stale connections? Stale in this context means that they have not emitted a close event but are no longer available.

Comment: socket.io (which uses a webSocket connection) adds a regular ping to both detect stale connections and to help keep network infrastructure from  timing out an inactive connection.  This is very doable to add yourself (the webSocket protocol even defines ping an pong packets) or you can just use socket.io at client and server and it will do it for you.

Answer (score 4):

There's no good way for you, on the client end of things, to know how many proxies, firewalls, NATs, *etc* occur in the network path from your client machine to the destination server.  Any one of those could have its own separate idle timer.  Using TCP keepalive *may* work, but **only** for the TCP session from your client to the next hop -- which may or may not actually be the end server.

Given the above, I would recommend that ***yes***, you *should* ping your connected WebSocket sessions periodically.  Whether you receive the pong from the server is, from the point of view of keeping your connections alive through that (possibly convoluted) chain of network middleboxes, irrelevant; you simply want to make sure that everything along the path sees *some* traffic flowing in order to reset their idle timers.

Obviously you want to trade off how often you ping your connected WebSocket sessions with how much overhead is incurred; pinging every 1 second would be a bit much, for example.  You may need some fine-tuning to determine, experimentally, just what a good ping interval is for your needs.

Hope this helps!